# Why can't I connect to my AWS RDS instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect with the username, password I've set up with the given host name. I can't connect. I've checked the security group to be configured correctly at PORT allowing incoming from "My IP" which populated my IP there.

What else could I be doing wrong?

When I try to get into the DB using the following command in my terminal:
`mysql -h [aws-hostname-endpoint] -P 3306 -u admin -p`

I get:
`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on [aws-hostname-endpoint] (60)`

Comment: where are you checking this locally or ec2 ?

Answer (score 1):

When you setup your RDS instance, also be sure to allow for public access if you want to connect to it from your development machine. SO two things to check:

1. allow public access for the RDS instance
2. make sure you inbound rules are setup to allow for a connection from your IP address.

Once you do these two tasks, you will be able to connect via a tool such as MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

These RDS endpoints are not public (and they shouldn't be), so you can't use them on your computer to connect to them. You could make these endpoints public, but that's not a good idea/design. It's better if you try to connect inside an AWS environment (i.e EC2). Then you can restrict access to that using SSH keys.

We usually create a [Bastion server](http://%20https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-ec2-bastion-host/) for this purpose to act as a proxy, then you can use an SSH tunnel to connect to the RDS instance. Then all your traffic will be routed through the Bastion server in a secured tunnel.